# Is it possible to move the tab bar to left and right direction in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im developing a tabbar application.

There are almost 7 tabs in this app.

Usuall when we add more than 5 tabs a "more button"will come and rest of options will come under that "More option".

But i found a very interesting app in app store and they are moving the tabbar to left and right(just like we do in scroll view) like in the image below.

How can i implement this.

Can anyone help me with this please.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: This is not possible with UITabbar. U need to create won controller with the combination of UIScrollView with UIButton's.

Comment: @SudeshKumar,so for highlighting the button in blue color we have to use another image?

Comment: Yes two image with two different event UIControlStateNormal and  UIControlStateSelected.Ex. [buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: To change the images according to selection, u need to set buttonName.selected = YES or NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom tabBar, like InfiniTabBar, nice and functional.

Project on GitHub:
https://github.com/iosdeveloper/InfiniTabBar

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, it's 2 custom UIButtons placed over the tabBar that may programmatically rearrange the tab options on their IBActions. What makes me say that is that the highlighted area of the last tab is just normal, and the arrows does not seem as well placed as what Apple could have done by standard.